# How do I create a deploy git branch for my Yeoman project?

Tags: git, deployment, gruntjs, yeoman, branching-and-merging

I created a new project using Yeoman. Using Grunt I've created the dist directory. My whole project is on Github, https://github.com/d3a1i0/mykungfuisstrong.com, and I've created a prod branch. My question is how do I get my prod branch to have only the contents of dist instead of having the dist directory and it's contents. That way when I work on the master and I want to deploy I can just commit the new changes to the prod branch. I'm trying to do this so I can set up grunt-build-control which I may have more questions about at another time.

Comment: Do you want to have two branches with absolutely different contents? What do you mean by "only the contents of dist instead of having the dist directory and it's contents."?

Comment: Thanks @NickVolynkin, I think maybe I'm asking the wrong question now that I think about it. My goal is to set up my app so that I can deploy it using Grunt-build-control as described on http://yeoman.io/learning/deployment.html. The way I read it was that I needed to end up with a branch that has only the production ready files. Those are in the dist directory so I was trying to figure out how to get a branch to only have the files in that directory without the dist directory itself. Perhaps I'm going about it all wrong.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Could you please explain what exactly do you want to have in your branch or directory?

Comment: I only want what is inside the dist directory. That is the files and sub directories of the dist folder. Currently the prod branch has the dist directory on it, but I only want what is under that. So what is in dist would actually be at the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc of `grunt-build-control`, the point of the task is that you don't need to worry about it.
The task **expects** a full branch that compiles to a build folder, and will handle the rest for you: building, then commiting the result to a local branch - and then pushing to the proper repo (like a Heroku deploy repo) if you wish to.

If you just want to commit to a branch, and it is called `prod`, your Gruntfile would be:

```
buildcontrol: {
    options: {
        dir: 'dist',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
    },
    build: {
        options: {
            remote: '../',
            branch: 'prod'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call `grunt buildcontrol:build`